# textarea value and text attributes goes on undefined in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a textarea

```
<textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
```

I need to fetch its value,I tried like this.

```
this.props.update(this.refs.newText.value,this.props.index);
```

I also used text instead of value but still it returns undefined.

```
this.refs.newText.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your react-dom libraries. ref help you to imperatively modify a child without the need to use props.[get the latest from react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html)

`src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js">
src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js">`

[Check out Refs & the DOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug without the full source code of your component. I've prepared a codepen which shows two ways of accessing the value entered in the `<textarea/>` element: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/amJAqb

Have a look also at the React Forms docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

```
const TextArea = React.createClass ({ 
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      userInputValue: '',
      userInputRefs: ''
    };
  },

  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
      userInputValue: event.target.value
    });
    this.setState({
      userInputRefs: this.refs.userData.value
    });   
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea ref="userData"
                  type="text"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={this.state.userInputValue} />
        <h3>User input value:</h3>
        <p>{this.state.userInputValue}</p>
        <h3>User input refs:</h3>
        <p>{this.state.userInputRefs}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
})


ReactDOM.render(
  <TextArea />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```